# How to display Multiple thumbnail images

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-view

How to display Multiple thumbnail images Below main product image. Right Now i am getting only one but on admin side having multiple.
[image]
Magento version 2.1.8

Comment: Plz verify with your product in backend, to whether you have ticked the options hide from product or not.

Comment: unchecked hide option from all images.

Comment: Please can you share backend screenshot of product image

Comment: could you check now after clearing cache.

Comment: http://nimb.ws/47WPhY see screen shot. yes i checked it by clearing cache but not getting success

Comment: https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-manage-product-images-in-magento-2-addremove/  see this i want http://nimb.ws/0tmPIT

Answer (score 1):

You just need to go to admin,

```
Catalog -> Manage Products
Edit Product,
```

Now

```
Check Hide From Product page checkbox is unchecked.
```

[image]
Clear cache and check.

Comment: Should i check or uncheck

Comment: you need to uncheck.

Comment: already unchecked all images.

Comment: could youshare your link?

Comment: not have a live site yet.

Comment: Is this confirm thing we can have multiple images in thumbnail???. because on admin site it allows only one image to set role for thumbnail.

Comment: you can set role for thumbnail,base and small image in only once.

Comment: See how they are show multiple images in thumbnails https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-manage-product-images-in-magento-2-addremove/

Answer (score 0):

There are few why you don't have thumbnails most common issues may be our ignorance.

1) Go to admin and check if you uploaded multiple images or not 
[image: image upload]

2) If there are no more than one product image or they are not checked as their role

[image: check role]
 as I did below 
[image: multiple roles]
3) Clear cache, or change the mode from production to development as it clear all cache perfectly if change back if website is in live mone or you can flush them as well

**OR**  Please check  as suggested by `@Rakesh Jesadiya`

In my case, all the images are shown as thumbnail

[image: thumbnail]

[image: hide]

Comment: I can exclusively set one role for only one image. I have 5 images but displaying only one.

Comment: Sir you set the roles for the images?

Comment: i want to show all images in tumbnail, but i can give thumbnail role to only one image. how can i show all.

Comment: http://nimb.ws/47WPhY want to show all images in thumbnail below main product image .

Comment: Ok i never did , let me check that too.

Comment: https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-manage-product-images-in-magento-2-addremove/  see this i want http://nimb.ws/0tmPIT